# Как получить значение JTextField в java swing?

Tags: java, swing, return, jtextfield

**Как вернуть значение от JTextField в java swing?**

Сразу предупреждаю я пробовал:

```java
String text = name.getText();
```

оно не работает, потому что когда я ввожу значение и нажимаю на <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то выводится то значение, которое вводится при создании самого виджета `JTextField`, но оно почему-то не работает после того как я ввел в поле символы и нажал <kbd>Enter</kbd>

***КОД:***

```java
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main {

    public static String SSID;
    public static Action Check = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(SSID);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wi-Fi info");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Pls enter SSID Wi-Fi");
        lbl.setSize(300, 30);
        lbl.setLocation(80, 5);

        JTextField Text_field = new JTextField();
        Text_field.setSize(285, 30);
        Text_field.setLocation(5, 50);
        Text_field.addActionListener(Check);
        String text = Text_field.getText();
        SSID = Text_field.getText();
        System.out.println(text);

        contentPane.add(lbl);
        contentPane.add(Text_field);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(310, 125);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение `SSID` присваивается ещё *до того*, как фрейм был отображён и пользователь успел что-то ввести в текстовое поле ввода.

Следует изменить определение `Action`, чтобы выводилось нужное значение из *источника события* `ActionEvent::getSource`, **после совершения действия пользователем**:

```java
public static Action Check = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        SSID = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
        System.out.println(SSID);
    }
};
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, все сработало!